# how to copya writablesheet to a different workbook in JExcel?

Tags: java, jxl

i'm trying to have a writablesheet created by some method and then be included to another workbook which was created by the caller context but I don't seem to have too many options on IMPORTING a writable sheet.

here's what I'm trying to do.

```
MainWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("file.xls"));
Sheet resultSheet = SheetCreator(/* some args */); //SheetCreator returns a writablesheet
```

But when I try to use the method Workbook.importsheet to copy the resultSheet to wb, it returns this error.

```
Message: jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl cannot be cast to jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl
```

Seems like I don't have the option to import a writablesheet?? Please shed some light

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast a WriteableSheet into a Sheet. I would take the approach to save the sheet and reload it as normal Sheet.

Comment: yeah, I guess I can do that or to make it a bit simpler I'll just place the sheet creator on the caller itself. but I think i'll still try to see my options with POI just to check.